# web pages stuck on "waiting for...", but then load fast

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, plesk

My website has a huge data base. Even this the frontpage with all content is 1.2MB. Small. I changed server because I wanted to load faster. In the old server when I clicked the url the site started to load serially, from the top to bottom. But in the new server I get the message "waiting for www..." in my browser down left for 4-5 sec and then my website displayed very quickly. When I remove one big mysql query, it is OK.

I downloaded the htaccess of boileplate, I put in Plesk hosting settings FastCGI application, but nothing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this issues due to mysql query then I will suggest you optimize your mysql services with MySQLTuner scripts. We have used that on for our some clients and it's working good. But make sure your mysql service up-time is more than 24 hours, so that you will get accurate suggestions in the script output.